# Coverage conditional in foreach loop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

My project use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to report the conditionals of an assert statement.
I have XCTest that expects and AssertionError to be thrown, and it passes correctly. The problem is that Jenkins reports that the assert branch was not covered.

```
for (NSString * string  in self.testArray) {
    NSLog(@"result %@",string);   
}
```

and Jenkins reports the coverages as:

```
Conditionals  80% (28/34)
```

I tried with testcase `testArray = nil` and `testArray` empty but the report isn't different. How can I pass this conditional test?

Comment: Are they all the code in the test method?